# Yii criteria Condition not working SQL error

Tags: php, mysql, yii

```
$criteria->condition .= 'UserID = '.$userId.' UNION
(
    SELECT * FROM display WHERE 
    UserID IN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM lkusergroup WHERE 
        GroupID IN
        (
            SELECT GroupID FROM lkusergroup WHERE UserID = '.$userId.'
        )
    )
)';
```

i m trying to execute above code but getting following error

```
    CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[21000]: 
Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns. The SQL statement executed was:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `display` `t` WHERE UserID = 2 UNION
        (
        SELECT * FROM display WHERE
        UserID IN
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM lkusergroup WHERE
        GroupID IN
        (
        SELECT GroupID FROM lkusergroup WHERE UserID = 2
        )
        )
    )
```

why query generating count(*) this is the actual issue. i tried may way to solve this error bt failed any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the count function in the below line also:

```
SELECT * FROM display WHERE 
    UserID IN
```

You code must be this:

```
$criteria->condition .= 'UserID = '.$userId.' UNION
(
    SELECT count(*) FROM display WHERE 
    UserID IN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM lkusergroup WHERE 
        GroupID IN
        (
            SELECT GroupID FROM lkusergroup WHERE UserID = '.$userId.'
        )
    )
)';
```

As at the time of UNION there must be return same number of columns from the query.

**EDITED:**

You query must be like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), * FROM display WHERE
    UserID IN
    (
       SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM lkusergroup WHERE
        GroupID IN
        (
           SELECT GroupID FROM lkusergroup WHERE UserID = 2
        )
    )
```

Comment: why count(*) i want column data not the count

Comment: if i write count(*) then error gets swapped ie query : SELECT * FROM `display` `t` WHERE UserID = 2 UNION
(
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM display WHERE
UserID IN
(
SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM lkusergroup WHERE
GroupID IN
(
SELECT GroupID FROM lkusergroup WHERE UserID = 2
)
)
)

Comment: @Chintan_chiku you does not need to swapped count. you need to either change your query, or use count at both place.

Comment: in criteria i cant only write condition not whole query